# Загрузка нескольких CSS вместо одного большого

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, http

В эпоху всяких gulpов, gruntов, webpackов возникает вопрос:
А нужно ли склеивать все файлы стилей?

Насколько мне известно, обработка неиспользуемых CSS-правил занимает какое-то время.

Итак, есть у меня Bootstrap. И есть у меня простая страница контактов. На странице контактов только сетка, пару кнопок и форма, когда бутстрап включает в себя ещё там разные стили для модальных окон, всяких каруселей и другой байды.

Так вот, мне кажется, ведь в 20 раз будет эффективнее вместо одного bootstrap.css, загрузить всего 3 - grid.css, buttons.css и forms.css? В отдельных файлах, а не в одном, чтобы на других страницах grid.css или buttons.css подгрузились из кеша.

Хотя, пока писал это и сам убедился, что будет гораздо эффективнее. Но почему это мало кто использует? Неужели потому, что проще всё сгрузить в один файл, чем в несколько?

Comment: Как именно поверил? И на какой скорости соединения? И 3 файла - это мало, подозреваю, что файлов обычно 50-500. Вот 2 меня 94 scss-файла есть - как предлагаешь их подключать?

Comment: А если есть только 3 файла, почти нет картинок и скриптов, т. е. суммарно получается меньше 8 соединений, то вполне верю, что пофайлово будет быстрее.

Comment: Ну да, предполагается http 1.1 или http 2? Во втором случае действительно теоретически должно быть лучше кучей файлов слать, хотя не видел исследований на эту тему.

Comment: Если используется первый http, то загрузка нескольких файлов (если их не три а дофига) дает ощутимый сетевой оверхед.  Практика класть все в один файл пошла именно из-за этого как я понимаю. Сейчас это уже наверное не сильно актуально.

Comment: Я не проверил, а, скорее, поверил. Просто тоже не много видел исследований на эту тему. Такая мысль пришла потому, что посмотрел какие стили загружает VK на разных страницах, а там они не сильно, но разбиты. Так вот подумал, что может если всё разбить, то и быстрее получится во много раз и решил спросить, может кто разбирается в этой теме глубже.

Comment: Проще загрузить один файл пусть в 100кб, чем много-много маленьких. Скорость интернета сейчас огромная, так-что время сейчас уходит больше на сам запрос-ответ с сервера, чем собственно на загрузку

Comment: @Crantisz, ну у мобилок не очень-то и огромная...

Answer (score 1):

Это не имеет особого смысла потому-что:

1. Стили бустрапа весят копейки и никто просто-напросто этим не замарачивается.
2. Вы не заметите никакой разницы в производительности.
3. Можно загрузить всего 3 стиля необходимых в вашем проэкте, это называется кастомизация, в bootstrap 3 есть целый раздел где вы выбираете что необходимо вам в вашем проэкте http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ .
4. В bootstrap 4 такая возможность есть через редактирования файла boostrap.scss.
   Там c помощью @import подключены отдельные файлы которые отвечают за те или иные вещи, просто напросто их там отключаете и собираете свой новый css скажем через gulp.